# Exported png edges are blurry

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I opened a SVG file with Photoshop. If I export at original size, it looks good, but If I export in smaller size, the edges are looking blurry:

[image]

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: On the last screenshot you have zoomed in to 600% (I can see that in the top of the window). When you zoom in on a raster (pixel) image you will see pixels. The image should be viewed at 100% to look good.

Answer (score 0):

Several things are happening here. First of all, this is not `Export`, this is `Save For Web` function. Those are different things.

Next, as @Wolff mentioned, you're zoomed to 600%: however, you may notice a black and white halo around edges. I'm not sure if that's the blurriness you're referencing to. If yes: I'm not sure why (a bug?), but when you resize image in the `Save For Web` dialog, PS will use `Bicubic` interpolation no matter if it's set to `Bicubic` or `Bilinear`. The black halos around edges are the result of `Bicubic` post-processing (it adds sharpen).

What you can do:

- use `File > Export > Export As...` function instead and set `Resample` to `Bilinear`. This won't produce any halos;
- if you want to use `Save for Web` (say you want to add it to an Action or save additional metadata): resize your image first (with `Resample` set to `Bilinear` in the `Image Size` dialog) and then save the image in 100% size.

If the halo isn't the blurriness you're referencing to, then it's just because you're zoomed in :)

Comment: This is the example you were looking for when you asked why does it matter what color the transparent pixel is. What you are seeing is the fully transparent pixels bleeding trough. Because Photoshop assumed those colors where in fact white. No such thing as a transparent pixel while scaling ;) And this is why i dont do signal processing in adobes software.

Comment: @joojaa But in this case there would be a white bleeding for no matter what color: those halos only appear for colored layers. I don't know the exact math behind the bicubic interpolation (I mean to say 'I wont understand' heh) but this effect is only visible on layers with color.

Comment: Well they woudld't be this desaturated.